# How to display UIkit nav outside of container?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, getuikit

I want to display a sticky UIkit nav outside of its container.

There is a very good example of how that could look on the UIkit website.
https://getuikit.com/docs/introduction
Ignore the links on the left.

The nav should be left side of the content (in the example, it's on the right)

I also made this example pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YoKxgB

```
<div class="uk-section">
    <div class="uk-container"></div>
</div>
```

https://i.ibb.co/nMhyz52/links.jpg

I really appreciate every answer

Comment: In the Codepen demo, the `nav` is on the left already. https://prnt.sc/nzxgcs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In UIKit there is a function called [sticky](https://getuikit.com/docs/sticky) which is meant for this. Just use `uk-sticky` with offset to keep it in place (here the offset is 70 from top).

You can find working code below (copied from your codepen)

```css
.admin-sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    width: 130px;
    left: -140px;
}
```

```html
<!-- UIkit CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.5/css/uikit.min.css" />

<!-- UIkit JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.5/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.5/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>

<div class="uk-section uk-section-default">
    <div class="uk-container" style="position: relative;">
        
       <div class="admin-sidebar uk-visible@xl">
          <!-- here we define uk-sticky with offset -->
          <div uk-sticky="offset:70">
            <ul class="uk-nav-default uk-nav-parent-icon" uk-nav>
                <li class="uk-nav-header">Navigation</li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="uk-margin-small-right" uk-icon="icon: users"></span>Benutzer</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="uk-margin-small-right" uk-icon="icon: thumbnails"></span>Gruppen</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="uk-margin-small-right" uk-icon="icon: unlock"></span>Rechte</a></li>
                <li class="uk-nav-divider"></li>
                <li><a href=""><span class="uk-margin-small-right" uk-icon="icon: server"></span>Server</a></li>
             </ul>
          </div>
       </div>
      
        <div>
            <div class="uk-panel uk-margin-medium">
                <h3>UIkit</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body">
                <p>Content #1<br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body">
                <p>Content #2<br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body">
                <p>Content #2<br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body">
                <p>Content #2<br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```